# Rust boxed closure in global variable

Tags: rust, static, global-variables

I'd like to store a boxed closure (`Box<dyn Fn(f64, f64) -> f64>`) in a global variable `EXPRESSION_FUNCTION`.

Here is my attempt at achieving this:

```rust
type F2d = Box<dyn Fn(f64, f64) -> f64>;

static mut EXPRESSION_FUNCTION: *mut F2d = 0 as *mut F2d;

fn create_function() -> F2d {
    Box::new(|_: f64, _: f64| 0.0)
}

fn set_expression_function() {
    unsafe {
        EXPRESSION_FUNCTION = Box::into_raw(create_function());
    }
}
```

I get a type mismatch:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\lib.rs:79:45
   |
79 |         EXPRESSION_FUNCTION = Box::into_raw(create_function());
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Box`, found trait object `dyn Fn`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Box<Box<(dyn Fn(f64, f64) -> f64 + 'static)>, _>`
              found struct `Box<(dyn Fn(f64, f64) -> f64 + 'static), std::alloc::Global>`
```

How can I convert the result of `create_function` to fit into a global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Do not use `static mut`.**](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53639) It is extremely easy to write incorrect programs that violate Rust's reference and aliasing rules using `static mut`. Instead, use `static` together with some kind of cell (interior-mutable type) — even `UnsafeCell` (which should be a last resort) is easier to use correctly than `static mut`.

If your variable is going to be initialized only once, the simplest solution is to use [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.OnceCell.html) (which is on its way to being included in the standard library, but for now is a widely used third-party library).

```rust
use once_cell::sync::OnceCell;

type F2d = Box<dyn Fn(f64, f64) -> f64 + Send + Sync>;

static EXPRESSION_FUNCTION: OnceCell<F2d> = OnceCell::new();

fn create_function() -> F2d {
    Box::new(|_: f64, _: f64| 2.0)
}

fn set_expression_function() {
    if let Err(_) = EXPRESSION_FUNCTION.set(create_function()) {
        panic!("already set");
    }
}

fn main() {
    set_expression_function();
    
    let f = EXPRESSION_FUNCTION.get().expect("not set");
    assert_eq!(f(10., 0.), 2.0);
}
```

If it needs to be reassignable, then you need a lock. [`parking_lot::RwLock`](https://docs.rs/parking_lot/latest/parking_lot/type.RwLock.html) is a nice choice because it can be constructed at compile time, so no lazy initialization is needed:

```rust
use parking_lot::RwLock;

type F2d = Box<dyn Fn(f64, f64) -> f64 + Send + Sync>;

static EXPRESSION_FUNCTION: RwLock<Option<F2d>> = RwLock::new(None);

fn create_function() -> F2d {
    Box::new(|_: f64, _: f64| 2.0)
}

fn set_expression_function() {
    *EXPRESSION_FUNCTION.write() = Some(create_function());
}

fn main() {
    set_expression_function();
    
    let option_fn_guard = EXPRESSION_FUNCTION.read();
    let f = option_fn_guard.as_ref().expect("not set");
    assert_eq!(f(10., 0.), 2.0);
}
```

Unlike the `static mut` you started with, both of these programs are sound (will not segfault, etc.) no matter how the functions and global variable are used. This is good Rust programming practice.

Comment: [`std::sync::Mutex::new()` is also `const`!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.new) (on nightly, or 1.63.0).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using `Some`:

```
type F2d = Box<dyn Fn(f64, f64) -> f64>;

static mut EXPRESSION_FUNCTION: Option<F2d> = None;

fn create_function() -> F2d {
    Box::new(|x: f64, y: f64| x+y)
}

fn set_expression_function() {
    unsafe {
        EXPRESSION_FUNCTION = Some(create_function());
    }
}

fn main() {
    set_expression_function();

    unsafe { 
        if let Some(f) = &EXPRESSION_FUNCTION{
            println!("{}", f(1.0, 2.0));
        }
    };
}
```